# C#, WPF, MVVM, Creating a viewmodel for message dialogs/confirmation dialogs?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog, confirmation

I am not using anything other than a simple WPF application project in visual studio. I've implemented an mvvm application.

I want to display a list of content changes made by a user. I have a main window view model and it currently just builds a strings with changes. I have objects that I can reuse to display their properties (the content).

Currently, I use a MessageBoxResult to show a really long string with the changes. This is a terrible design (I know), but I couldn't really find an  answer to what class a regular wpf project has that would allow me to achieve what I want.

I know there is a popup class I can use. In practice, which is better-- another view model for the dialog, or a popup?

Can anyone provide a simple example of one of the two approaches?

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past is have a simple `Border` control, and inside of a `TextBlock` and whatever `Button` controls I need.  I bind the `TextBlock.Text` to a public `string` property named "MessageBoxMessage" which calls `OnPropertyChanged()`.  I bind the `Command` of each `Button` to a separate public `ICommand` which specifies what action to take in the view model when the button is clicked.  I then bind the visibility of the `Border` control - which contains all of the other controls I mentioned - to a Visibility property.

When I want to show a dialog, I set the MessageBoxMessage to the message I want to show, makes sure the commands are set properly, and then set the `Visibility` on the `Border` to `Visibility.Visible`.  This shows the box (border), message, and buttons.

You can even implement a semi-transparent rectangle underneath the border (over the rest of the form) that you set to visible at the same time.  This will give you the nice "form dimmed" effect and also block the normal form controls from being clicked.  A general note - for this to work, these controls need to be at the very bottom of your XAML as the z-index among controls at the same level is inferred from their placement in the XAML - lower in the code is top level on the form.

Let me know if you have any questions about implementing this if it sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't know what about the placement of the controls in the xaml. I am hoping to hand a way of reusing some of the object I display in the main window. I think I will give this a shot.